# Cycles. Two Glas windows behind one another makes them black

Tags: texturing, shaders, glass, photorealism

I am doing a a glas sliding door that is open and the part that overlaps gets very dark. I am using the glas shader on both.

Oh and if we are at it. Would be thankful for anytips to make the glas door look more realistic. I added some water stains as imperfections. I feel like the glas does not reflect at all though what makes it almost invisible

Both doors behind eachother:

[image]

Just a bit overlapping:

[image]

Comment: Well it surely helped with the realism but the part where my doors overlap still appear dark

Comment: is it not a Z fighting? what does it give if they don't overlap anymore?

Comment: Z fighting? if they dont oberlap it looks good.

Comment: It might be related to the light path sample count. Does it go away when you increase the [*Transparent* count in *Preferences > Light Paths > Max Bounces*](https://i.imgur.com/MlfT5kK.png)?

Comment: Nice Thank you! It was not the transparent one though. I raised the Transmission and now it works. Still does not look realistic but I will work on that. Thanks!!